# How do you interpret the answer to a Bayes' Theorem Question?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem

A traffic control engineer believes that the cars passing through a particular intersection arrive at a constant mean rate λ equal to either 2 or 4 every 10 minutes. Prior to collecting any data, the engineer believes that it is much more likely that the rate is 2. In fact, the engineer's prior probabilities are $P(λ = 2) = 0.75$ and $P(λ = 4) = 0.25$. One day, during a randomly selected 10 minute interval, the engineer observes x = 6 cars pass through the intersection.

In light of the observation that x = 6, calculate the posterior probabilities that λ = 2 and λ = 4, and hence discuss how the traffic control engineer's beliefs have been altered by the observation.

My Solution: Using Baye's theorem for λ = 2 , I get the following:

$P(λ = 2 |x = 6) = \frac{P(x = 6 | λ = 2)(P(λ = 2)}{P(x = 6)}$

Using the probability density formula for the Poisson distribution, $P(X = x) = \frac{λ^{x}e^{-λ}}{x!}$ , I get:

$P(λ = 2 | x = 6) = \frac{\frac{2^{6}e^{-2}}{6!}  (0.75)}{\frac{2^{6}e^{-2}}{6!} + \frac{4^{6}e^{-4}}{6!}}$

Finally, I get $P(λ = 2 | x = 6) = 0.077628034$ and when I repeat the method for λ = 4, I get $P( λ = 4|x = 6) = 0.2241239887$.

The part I don't understand is how to comment on the traffic engineer's beliefs in light of these findings. Initially, I thought that the prior probability for $P(λ = 4) = 0.25$ was very close to the observed value of $P(λ = 4|x = 6)$ and therefore his suspicions were correct. However the observed value of $P(λ = 2|x = 6)$ is roughly 10 times smaller than $P(λ = 2)$ which makes me think I have done something wrong as $P( λ = 2|x = 6)$ and $P(λ = 4|x = 6)$ don't sum to 1, like the prior probabilities do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134244/discussion-on-question-by-uckfield-2-how-do-you-interpret-the-answer-to-a-bayes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to flesh out the comments:

This is a routine application of Bayes Theorem.

Using the standard Poisson distribution, we see that the probability of observing $6$ cars given that $\lambda =2$ is $.0120298$ and that with $\lambda =4$ it is $.10419563$

Now, using the given prior probabilities, the re-estimated probability that $\lambda =2$ should be $$\frac {.75\times .0120298}{.75\times .0120298+.25\times .10419563}= .25725711$$

so that the estimated probabilities have effectively switched.  Now the engineer sees a (roughly) $75\%$ chance that $\lambda = 4$ and only a $25\%$ chance that $\lambda = 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand the solution now. Sorry if I was being painfully stupid!